# How do I put a background image on a text area (IN THE IPAD)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ipad

How do I put a template'd background image on a text area?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "template'd"... but....

In interface builder, add the imageview behind the textview, uncheck the "opaque" box for the textview.

Comment: How do you put an imageview behind the textview?

Comment: You just drop an image view in, you might have to change the z order of the textview so that it is above the image view.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the contents property of the text views layer.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"].CGImage
}
```

should work

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add the image programmaticaly I managed to do it this way:

First in my textviewViewController.h I added an outlet for the UITextView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface textviewViewController : UIViewController {
UITextView *textView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end
```

Next, in my .xib I added my UITextView and connected my outlet.

Lastly in the viewDidLoad of textviewViewController.m I add the image as a subview to my textview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Change the pathForResource to reflect the name and type of your image file
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"d" ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.textView insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];
    [imgView release];

}
```

I tried the insertSubview:atIndex: with both 0 and 1 with the same result, but I would stick with 0 idicating that it's behind the textview.

Comment: `[self.textView insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];` inserts the image into, not behind, the textView.  Use `[[self.textView superview] insertSubview:imgView belowSubview:self.textView];` to put it behind the textView, assuming superview is not nil.  The latter will not scroll with the text.  And don't forget to release imgView after inserting it.

Comment: thanks drawnonward, you're right I forgot to release my imgView. Since this is in my view controller the imageView could be inserted into the main view with a [self.view insertSubview:] but I got the impression that the imageView was wanted as part of the textview.